# custom useState with handler not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I have created a custom hook with callback to use it as setState in Class Component. But it is showing unexpected behaviour.

```
import {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react'

export function useStateWithCallback(initialState:any) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const callbackRef:any = useRef(null);
    
    const dispatchAction = useCallback((obj:any, callback:any)=>{
        callbackRef.current = callback;
        setState(obj);
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(callbackRef.current){
            callbackRef.current(state);
            callbackRef.current = null;
        }
    },[state]);

    return [state, dispatchAction];
}
```

usage of this hook

```
const [orderId, setOrderId] = useStateWithCallback(0);

const postOrder = useCallback(()=>{

//After successfully posted order

  setOrderId(ordId, (newOrdId:string)=>{
     console.log('newOrdId: '+newOrdId);
     console.log('orderId: '+orderId);
  });

},[]);
```

what I get in console is displayed below:

**newOrdId: 8438247**

**orderId: 0**

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Comment: Please describe the *"unexpected behaviour"*. If it's the fact that `orderId` does not match `newOrdId`, then refer to the link above.